# Why do some command boxes in XP keep the internal name "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"?

Tags: windows-xp, console

If I start a windows console from a bat file in windows XP, some of the boxes get the name of the bat file it is started from, but other files still result in the standard "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" name.

I am trying to give different windows console different colors.
Windows XP recognises the boxes by their name.

I tried using `TITLE Bar startscreen` as the first sentence in the file, which causes the title to be shown in the titlebar and in the toolbar. However when I select the screen's properties it is still called "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe".

A difference between these two files is that the working one is located on my hard drive and the other on an USB-stick. The first starts Eclipse and the second starts Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The difference was caused by whether or not I used a shortcut. 
Using a shortcut, windows XP has a location for saving the meta properties of the window, like preferred colors (in 255 255 255 format).

So I was able to change the colors by also using shortcuts for the other bat files.